# Why are some conferences no longer indexed by Scopus?

Tags: conference, computer-science, indexing, scopus

I have seen in Scopus that there are some conferences that are still running nowadays, but they not longer appear indexed on Scopus. For example, in the field of Computer Science I see that the ICCSIT conference is indexed only until 2010, but now they are in the 2015 edition. I know that some indexing units such as DBLP exclude from their current rankings some conferences when their quality has decreased substantially. Does this situation also happen with Scopus?

Comment: Scopus coverage of conferences has always been spotty at best.  Exclusion really doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 2):

Scopus, just like DBLP, has standards.  In fact, if you look at [Scopus' description of the conference coverage](http://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/content), it appears that they actually just scrape DBLP to get their computer science conference listings.  As such, while I don't know about the particular conference that you mention, I would expect that anything that DBLP drops, Scopus will drop as well.